# Solving first-order RL circuits

Tags: inductor

I apologize if this is a repeated question, but I couldn't find one that had the answers I need.

For the circuit in the diagram, the switch has been closed for a long time and at \$t=0\$, the switch is opened. In solving the circuit, the textbook first considers \$t<0\$, during which the switch is closed, the inductor acts as a short circuit, and \$16 \Omega\$ resistor is also short-circuited.

My questions are: Why is the inductor shorted? Why is the resistor also shorted?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resistor is not a short circuit at any point, only the [inductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor). What you may have meant is that the inductor being a short circuit will effectively take the resistor out of the circuit after the switch has been closed for a long time (16Ω in parallel with 0Ω = 0Ω, so regardless of the resistor value it has no effect on the circuit during this time)

The formula for the voltage across an ideal inductor is:

\$ V(t) = L \dfrac{dI(t)}{dt} \$

This means that unless the current is changing (dI), there is 0V across the inductor, i.e:

\$  V(t) = L\dfrac{0}{dt} = 0V \$

Equivalent circuit for the switch closed steady state:

[image: Steady State Equivalent]

Comment: Why is the 16Ω resistor considered to be in parallel with 0Ω when it is connected to a 4Ω resistor and the rest of the circuit?

Comment: Because it *is* in parallel :-) Regardless of the rest of the circuit, two components that share the same nodes at either end are in parallel, that's the definition of the term. This means we can simplify the circuit for analysis by combining the two (or more) components into one equivalent value. In this case (when the switch is closed and a steady current is flowing) these two components can be replaced with a short circuit. You may want to revise parallel/series circuits, Thevenin, and work on a few of these circuits until it becomes clear.

Comment: I added the simplified circuit for the switch closed, DC steady state case - this is how it looks to the rest of the circuit (remember the inductor is still there in reality) Hopefully this makes sense. We could simplify further if we want to, I'll leave that for you to look at.

Comment: Forgive me if I am being stubborn, but if we were to short the inductor but leave the 16Ω resistor in your diagram, in the steady state case, the final result for the current through the inductor at t>0 would be the same right?

Comment: No, the above is only for t < 0. After t > 0 the 16 Ohm resistor does have an effect on the circuit, because the inductor is no longer a short circuit and there is a voltage present across the 16 Ohm resistor.

Answer (score 3):

In an ideal inductor, the real part of its impedance is zero, so in the steady state DC case, it is a short to DC. In your schematic, it is a short to the negative terminal of the voltage source, which puts both ends of the 16 ohm resistor at that potential. All DC current will flow through the inductor. This is important for t > 0.